# How to handle with hasDatepicker class - IE Automation

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have such peas of code that open web page with two input boxes. I am trying to display a currency table with a different date than the default, but it does not work. Everything is fine only while mouse clicking on "Report" button - then I can display any date.
Does anyone have any idea?

I have already tried with: "Application.SendKeys ("{ENTER}"), True" and with different date format. I was also looking for information about hasDatepicker class...

```
Sub getDataFrombrowser()

 Dim address As String
 Dim browser As InternetExplorer

 Set browser = New InternetExplorerMedium
 With browser
     .Visible = True
 End With

 address = "http://www.nbrm.mk/kursna_lista-en.nspx"

 With browser
     .navigate address
     Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
     .navigate address
     Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
 End With

 browser.document.getElementsByClassName("form-control sdate hasDatepicker")(0).Value = Format(Date - 1, "DD.MM.YYYY")
 browser.document.getElementsByClassName("form-control edate hasDatepicker")(0).Value = Format(Date - 1, "DD.MM.YYYY")

 Set objCollection = browser.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
objCollection(7).Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the POST request the page does and use XMLHTTP rather than a slow browser. You get a json response. You can use a json parser to handle this and extract what info you want. I extract everything. Headers are in Slovenian but you could substitute with your own hardcoded English values. View full example json response [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=4e2f9e01953e4bcb99bc7fce2ead0d2d).

Download json parser [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas)

You specify the start and end dates in the body of the request.

```
Public Sub GetRates()
    'install https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas and add to project
    'VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library
    Dim json As Object, body As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, results(), headers()

    body = "{""startDate"":""23.03.2019"",""endDate"":""21.04.2019"",""isStateAuth"":""0""}"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "http://www.nbrm.mk/services/ExchangeRates.asmx/GetEXRates", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "http://www.nbrm.mk/kursna_lista-en.nspx"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(body)
        .send body

        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)

        Dim ratesParent As Object, rates As Object, rate As Object, header As Object

        Set ratesParent = json("d")
        Set header = ratesParent.item(1)("ExchangeRates").item(1)

        ReDim results(1 To 10000, 1 To header.Count)
        ReDim headers(1 To header.Count)
        Dim key As Variant, c As Long, r As Long

        headers = header.keys

        For Each rates In ratesParent       
            For Each rate In rates("ExchangeRates")                  'dictionaries
                r = r + 1: c = 1
                For Each key In rate.keys
                    results(r, c) = rate(key)
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            Next 
        Next
        With ws
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
            .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, it looks amaizing! It is so fast!

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure how to handle with objects and so one, but I will try. I have already prepared over 30 web pages (except this one) but I did not know that such magic is so close :) I will try to use this solution and will get back with feedback or questions! THANK YOU!

Comment: In Json if you see [] it is a collection you for each over or index into. If you see {} it is a dictionary you can loop the keys of or access by key

Comment: The .responseText is Json and you could write it to file and then copy paste into an online Json viewer and use it to examine the structure and work paths to desired elements

Comment: Any questions on this?

Comment: Oh yes, I have number of questions, but let's start with first one:
How did you get this address? http://www.nbrm.mk/services/ExchangeRates.asmx/GetEXRates. 
I am asking because I will try to use this solution to all of sites I need, but first I need to know how does it work :)

Comment: Open dev tools network tab (F12) - I use Chrome by preference. Load your page. Press Ctrl + F to pull up search box - enter a value that is present in the webpage that you are hoping to find in the web traffic. Press enter. If you get search results they will be listed and you can scroll through the results to examine which requests the page was making and see if there is a nice API/XHR call being made which you can use instead for data. That is what I did to get this url.

Comment: Yes, that is clear for me, but the question is how you fifure out this. Did you get getExchangeRates() function from the button and then serch fore something more? How did you find "services" catalog?

Comment: Maybe it is not easy to explain, but for now this part is much harder for me then the code